# Forms not showing up when using a registration app

Tags: python, django

I'm using this app to register the user of my website https://github.com/egorsmkv/simple-django-login-and-register. The problem is that no metter what I do my form are not visible (they were when I did not use this registration app and the code worked just fine). This is my code:

model

```
class UserBio(models.Model):     
   name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   age = models.CharField(max_length=2)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)    
   height = models.CharField(max_length=3)
   weight = models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

form

```
class UserBio(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = UserBio
       fields = (name', 'age', 'phone', 'height', 'weight')
```

views

```
def add_bio(request):
   submitted = False
   if request.method == "POST":
       info_form = UserBio(request.POST)
       if info_form.is_valid():        
           info_form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('add_information?submitted=True')
   else:
       info_form = UserBio()
       if 'submitted' in request.GET:
           submitted = True
   return render(request, 'accounts/profile/add_information.html', {'form': info_form, 'submitted':submitted})
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('add/information', views.add_information, name='add_information'),   
]
```

html

```
{% extends 'layouts/default/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Add info {% endblock %} 

{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}

   <h4>{% trans 'Add Info' %}</h4>

   {% if submitted %}
   Sumitted correctly

{% else %}
   <form method="post">       
   {% csrf_token %}    

   {{ info_form.as_p }}

   </form>
   </div>
   <br/>
</body>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be very apprecieted!

Answer (score 0):

because in your views def add_bio change your url acc to your function views

```
path('add/information', views.add_bio, name='add_information'),
```

and in you template

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Comment: kome your problem solved or not by my answer

Answer (score 0):

You passed the `info_form` variable to the template with variable name `form`. Indeed:

```
#                            name of the variable for the template ↓
return render(request, 'accounts/profile/add_information.html', {'form': info_form, 'submitted':submitted})
```

This thus means that you render this with:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

You should also trigger the correct view:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('add/information/', views.add_bio, name='add_information'),   
]
```

The path does *not* point to the template: a path points to a view, and the view *can* (this is not required) render zero, one or multiple templates to create a HTTP response.